# Wrap bb code around selected text in a content editable DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to create an RTE environment. 
I have a content editable div and I would like to allow the user to select text and then press a button which would wrap BBCode around it.

I have tried creating the following function, However, the selected text is just replaced.
It doesn't seem to be storing the proper valu ein selectedText

```
function wrap(tag) 
{


    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection)
     {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount)
         {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var selectedText = range;
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode('['+tag+']'+selectedText+'[/'+tag+']'));
        }
    } 
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) 
    {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
        console.log(text);
        range.text = '['+tag+']'+text+'[/'+tag+']';
    }
}


</script>
```

JQuery is acceptable but I'd prefer regular Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `selectedText = range;` to `selectedText = range.toString();`. The range is an object and when you do deleteContents it wipes out the data and so it doesn't wrape.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/73YXM/)

**JS:**

```
function wrap(tag) {
    var sel, range;
    var selectedText;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();

        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            selectedText = range.toString();
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode('[' + tag + ']' + selectedText + '[/' + tag + ']'));
        }
    }
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text + "";
        range.text = '[' + tag + ']' + selectedText + '[/' + tag + ']';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
var selectedText = range.toString();
```

rather than

```
var selectedText = range;
```

... because the range will contain no text after its `deleteContents()` method has been called.

One other note: `console.log(text);` will throw in the IE branch if you run it in a version of IE without a console or with console disabled.

Comment: That was just there for debugging. :) Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer that was here does work, but only if there is no images in the selection. I've simplified it and made it work with images in the selection as well:

https://jsfiddle.net/skeets23/go1nxf06/

```
function wrap(tag) {

  sel = window.getSelection();

  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(document.createTextNode("["+tag+"]"));
    range.collapse();
    range.insertNode(document.createTextNode("[/"+tag+"]"));
  }

}
```

Since I'm working on an internal project, I didn't bother making it compatible with all browsers like in the other answer, but it works in the current versions of firefox and chrome. Does not work in IE.